# Windows install hadoop fail to format

Tags: hadoop

I don't know why this is error is happening in Hadoop version 2.7.1.

```
$ ./hadoop namenode –format
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

15/12/31 22:26:34 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = ZKCRJB84CNJ0ZTJ/172.29.66.77
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [▒Cformat]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.7.1
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = 

C:\hadoop\etc\hadoop;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\li                                                                                                                b\activation-1.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.j                                                                                                                ar;
C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar;

leave out

C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\                                                                                                                mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapred                                                                                                                uce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hado                                                                                                                op-mapreduce-client-hs-2.7.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapredu                                                                                                                ce-client-hs-plugins-2.7.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce                                                                                                                -client-jobclient-2.7.1-tests.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapred                                                                                                                uce-client-jobclient-2.7.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce                                                                                                                -client-shuffle-2.7.1.jar;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-exam                                                                                                                ples-2.7.1.jar;C:\cygwin\contrib\capacity-scheduler\*.jar;C;C:\hadoop\contrib\ca                                                                                                                pacity-scheduler\*.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 15e                                                                                                                cc87ccf4a0228f35af08fc56de536e6ce657a; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2015-06-29T06:04                                                                                                                Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_51
************************************************************/
15/12/31 22:26:34 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [▒Cformat]
Usage: java NameNode [-backup] |
        [-checkpoint] |
        [-format [-clusterid cid ] [-force] [-nonInteractive] ] |
        [-upgrade [-clusterid cid] [-renameReserved<k-v pairs>] ] |
        [-upgradeOnly [-clusterid cid] [-renameReserved<k-v pairs>] ] |
        [-rollback] |
        [-rollingUpgrade <rollback|downgrade|started> ] |
        [-finalize] |
        [-importCheckpoint] |
        [-initializeSharedEdits] |
        [-bootstrapStandby] |
        [-recover [ -force] ] |
        [-metadataVersion ]  ]

15/12/31 22:26:34 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ZKCRJB84CNJ0ZTJ/172.29.66.77
************************************************************/
```

Comment: I don't see an error... Are you sure you typed `-format` and not `—format`? (different dashes)

Comment: oh ,let me try again,I am a Chinese ,English is not that much of good,today is the last day of 2015,Happy new year,thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your args = [▒Cformat], use the correct dash sign `-` not `—`.

Comment: today is the last day of 2015,Happy new year,thank you for your answer,I have solved it.